# How to parse and return variables in python

Tags: python

I wrote this script to interact with nessus and tell me what reports were in the nessus list:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from NessusXMLRPC import Scanner
import sys
x = Scanner("localhost", "8834", login="root", password="password123")
report = str(x.reportList())
print report
x.logout
```

I now want to take the output:

```
root@bt:~/NessusXMLRPC-0.21# ./reportfornessus.py 
[{'status': 'running', 'readableName': 'SecondScan', 'name': '76c25e9b-8280-5310-23e8-f9873255c5a6288ff86b03b2cdb6', 'timestamp': '1328641639'}, {'status': 'running', 'readableName': 'Third Scan', 'name': '01b2a026-44d3-574c-08e3-e6c97e3f8e21c7c00ec9cb71a7cd', 'timestamp': '1328641704'}]
```

and parse through it looking for my specifically passed 'readableName' and then return the 'status' for that scan.

Comment: Are you unclear on how to use lists and dictionaries?  Do you need to find a tutorial?  Those things are covered (thoroughly) in most tutorials.  Which have you been using to learn Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scn = Scanner("localhost", "8834", login="root", password="password123")
reports = scn.reportList()
for r in reports:
    if r["readableName"] == SOME_NAME:
        print r["status"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Does the r["X"] refer to the result?

Comment: @S-Ns-3: "Could you refer me to a good one".  Please use search first and then ask **specific** questions.  We don't know what "good" means to you.